# Let JSF set selected items of selectManyListbox value as List or Collection instead of array

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, collections, selectmanylistbox

Is there a way to get selected items from the selectManyListbox as a List orCollection? After submit the items selected always come as arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `collectionType` attribute to the FQN of the desired collection implementation.

E.g. if you want JSF to set the selected items in an instance of `java.util.ArrayList`:

```
<h:selectManyListbox ... collectionType="java.util.ArrayList">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , one alternative would be creating a method in your backing bean to return the array variable as List

```
 public java.util. List<String> getItemAsList(){
  return java.util.Arrays.asList(this.item);
    }
```

In case you need to output the items , you can use ui:repeat (pressumably you're using Facelets)

```
  <ui:repeat value="#{yourBean.itemAsList}" var="item">
    #{item}
  </ui:repeat>
```

Comment: What if I need to bind selected value to a collection ?

the mentioned alternative is exactly what I'm avoiding.

Comment: an alternative means this is one of the some ways you can retrieve the values of array as List, and the selected values are already binded through the List. by returning the method